# Rust ndarray, arithmetic operations over owned values

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I've been trying to understand how using owned Arrays works. So I tried to write this function and it doesn't compile.

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;
fn add_arrays<T>(ar1 : &Array1<T>, ar2 : &Array1<T>) -> Array1<T>
    where T : Add+Sub+Div+Mul
{
    ar1 + ar2
}
```

But i get this error :

```
binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<T>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`

note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<T>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
```

i'd like to know what should be done to do this

Answer (score 1):

You should use [LinalgScalar](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/trait.LinalgScalar.html) trait

```
use ndarray::*;

fn add_arrays<T>(ar1: &Array1<T>, ar2: &Array1<T>) -> Array1<T>
where
    T: LinalgScalar,
{
    ar1 + ar2
}

fn main() {
    let a = array![1.0, 2.0];
    let b = array![3.0, 4.0];
    let c = add_arrays(&a, &b);
    println!("{:?}", c);
}
```